# Where are the Xubuntu download verification check sums?

Tags: xubuntu, 20.04

I just downloaded Xubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) and would like to verify the file is OK before I transfer it to a USB drive.

But I couldn't find any checksum on the [release](https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-20-04-released/)/[download](https://xubuntu.org/release/20-04/) pages, and using a search engine didn't help either.

Where are they hiding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's at http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/20.04/release/

The documentation page that points you to all hashes for all supported releases and flavors is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, but is there a secure page to source this from? *cdimage.ubuntu.com* doesn't support HTTPS.

Comment: @FriendFX The actual installer download page is secure (https), so the worst a maliciously redirected sums file could do is trick you into believing that you didn't have a good download.

Comment: Fair enough. Still funny how much easier this would be (even with insecure downloads) if Xubuntu adopted [Ubuntu's model](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04&architecture=amd64#) (click on "verify your dowload") as in `echo "005a9450d16fe885132be9368a96c73910096b57cc1a67f03a97fca7af95f4a3 *xubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso" |shasum -a 256 --check`

Comment: FYI: The 20.04 Desktop installer verifies it's own hash at each boot, which has led to a substantial decrease in common my-installer-doesn't-work questions here...and a minor increase in complaints about I-want-that-minute-of-my-life-back

Comment: Yes, I noticed that with the Ubuntu 20.04 download. Luckily it can be interrupted. Also note a maliciously modified installer could of course either verify against its own checksum or fake the check altogether, which is why I prefer checking the downloaded file instead.

Comment: @user535733 the link to download the .ISO is http not https.  The worst a malicious actor could do would be to MITM and completely hikack and serve their own malicious ISO alongside a different checksum that would show that the malicious download is hunky dory.

Comment: @Nmath https://ubuntu.com/download, where most folks get Ubuntu from, is https.

Comment: @user535733 You responded to the comment from OP about concerns with securely downloading the ISO from *cdimage.ubuntu.com* and reassured OP that the download from there is secured:  It's not.  https://github.com/canonical-web-and-design/ubuntu.com/issues/4394

Comment: @Nmath I'm open to suggestions for rephrasing, of course, to prevent confusion. I most certainly did NOT suggest downloading anything except the hash file from a non-secure site.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [answer by user535733](https://askubuntu.com/a/1260987/181442) doesn't outline the [verification procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto), I thought I add it here for convenience.

Note that you should replace the key ID (`0xD94AA3F0EFE21092`) with whatever you get back from the first `gpg` call.

```
wget http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/20.04/release/SHA256SUMS http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/20.04/release/SHA256SUMS.gpg
gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg --keyid-format long --list-keys --with-fingerprint 0xD94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS
```

Adapted from Ubuntu's download/verify page, this one-liner could (and I think should) be on Xubuntu's download page:

```
echo "005a9450d16fe885132be9368a96c73910096b57cc1a67f03a97fca7af95f4a3 *xubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso" |shasum -a 256 --check
```